# how to parse 2019-08-01T16:20:00+02:00 datetime using php

Tags: php, mysql, json

```
"data": {
  "weather": {
    "iataCode": "MUC",
    "at": "2019-08-01T16:20:00+02:00"
  },
  "weather": {
    "iataCode": "BKK",
    "at": "2019-08-02T08:50:00+07:00"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this format to generate a date like above

```
<?php echo date(DATE_W3C); ?>
```